# How to get long click events on Android main thread with a delay using Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

The solution that I have might not be elegant the way it is written using a Handler, but gives me the desired experience, where for a long click event as long as the button is pressed, some ui process should happen and that process should be delayed a little bit because the stream of events is fast, I want to do the similar experience using Kotlin's coroutine API.

```
button.setOnLongClickListener {
        val handler = Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!)
        val runnable: Runnable = object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this)
                if (nextButton.isPressed) {
                    Log.e("Press", "Thread name: ${handler.looper.thread.name} ")
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 500)
                }
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0)
        true
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like so.

```kotlin
button.setOnLongClickListener {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        while (isActive && nextButton.isPressed) {
            Log.e("Press", "Thread name: ${handler.looper.thread.name} ")
            delay(500)
        }
    }
    true
}
```

NOTE: Don't use `GlobalScope` like I did! Use `lifecycleScope` or whatever makes sense.

Comment: Burying the lede a little bit... use `lifecycleScope` if it's an Activity and `viewLifecycleScope` if it's a Fragment. I bring it up because I see GlobalScope used when it shouldn't in many questions and answers here.